# Optimize Entity Framework query with multiple contain statements

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, entity-framework

I'm trying to optimize a query which is taking around 6 seconds to execute.

```
string[] filters = ...;   

var data =
   (from n in ctx.People
        .Where(np => np.IsActive)
    let isFilterMatch = filters.All(f => n.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(f) ||
                                         n.Prefix.ToLower().Contains(f) ||
                                         n.MiddleName.ToLower().Contains(f) ||
                                         n.LastName.ToLower().Contains(f) ||
                                         n.Information.Email.ToLower().Contains(f) ||
                                         (n.Address!= null &&
                                          (SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)n.Address.Number).
                                               Contains(f) ||
                                           n.Address.Street.ToLower().Contains(f) ||
                                           n.Address.ZipCode.ToLower().Contains(f) ||
                                           n.Address.City.ToLower().Contains(f))))
    where isFilterMatch
    orderby n.LastName
    select n
    ).Take(numberOfItems).ToList();
```

This is a query for a search dialog. The user can type in any text and it will then search for a person that matches the input. We split the user input into a string array and then do a Contains on the Person fields. The query cannot be precompiled because of the filter array.

How can I optimize this function? I heard about things like FullTextSearch on Sql Server or stored procedures. Could that help?

We are using Sql Server 2008, Entity Framework 4.0 (Model First) and C#.

Comment: Have you added indexes on all your filter fields to the DB?

Comment: @JustinHarvey My columns are of type nvarchar(max). I can't add an index to them. I get the message that the type is not valid for a key column in an index.

Comment: @Wouter, I can't get that why you need 'nvarchar(max)' for FirstName, MiddleName, LastName etc. How long a FirstName can be? It should be max nvarchar(50) if there is not other reason to continue with (max)

Comment: @Wouter Yes, it won't let you for nvarchar(max), do they really need to be this type?  If you specify a fixed size to the nvarchar it will let you add an index, which is what I do think you need.

Comment: <Shame> ;) We don't need nvarchar. The database was generated with a Model First approach and EF makes all strings nvarchar by default.

Comment: @JustinHarvey I added the indexes. Brings query time down to 5 seconds.

Comment: One thing you could try would be to write the SQL for your query and run that directly against your DB with some dummy values.  If that is alot better, it might then be worth following the stored procedure route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not use a SQL query / Linq query for this search query. Normal queries for text searching can be slow and they only return exact results; they don't correct spelling/grammar errors etc.

You might consider using the 'Full Text Search' functionality of SQL Server; but the resulting performance might be still poor. Please refer to http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2010/full-text-search-2008/.

I would suggest to use a search indexer like Apache Lucene (which is available as a dll in Lucene.NET). Another option is that you write your own Windows service that indexes all the records.